# Apache Cassandra Server and Datastax Client - Changing IP Addresses

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax

We are using the latest Apache Cassandra database server, and the Datastax Node.js client, running in the cloud.

When our Cassandra servers are rebuilt, they get new IP addresses. Then any running service clients can't find the new servers, the client driver obviously must cache the IP addresses, instead of using DNS.

Is there some way around this problem, other than doing client shutdown and get a new client, in our services when we encounter an error accessing the database?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 1 server, there is nothing you can do. 
Otherwise the node when it rebuilds (if it is a single node in the cluster of many) will advertise the new IP to the cluster and cluster topology is updated. So the peers table will be updated and the driver can register this event (AFAIK).

But why not use private static addresses for your cassandra nodes?